# numba and numpy: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '__code__'

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.6, numba

I tried this code

```
from numba import jit
from numpy import arange
@jit
def sum2d(arr):
    M, N = arr.shape
    result = 0.0
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(N):
            result += arr[i,j]
    return result

a = arange(9).reshape(3,3)
print(sum2d(a))
```

and got a runtime exception: `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '__code__'`

I cannot find any version requirement on numpy in numba's documentation. Currently I have numpy 1.7.1 installed. My python version 2.6.6

What is the cause of the **AttributeError**?

**EDIT**

Some stacktrace info;

```
 File "c:\pylib\numba\decorators.py", line 228, in _jit_decorator
    if func.__code__.co_argcount == 0 and argtys is None:
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '__code__'
Locals:
argtypes: 'None'
  argtys: 'None'
     env: 'NumbaEnvironment(numba)'
env_name: 'None'
    func: '[[0 1 2]\n [3 4 5]\n [6 7 8]]'
  kwargs: '{backend:ast}'
 restype: '<function sum2d at 0x1C89F5F0>'
```

Comment: This works for me with numpy 1.8.0 and numba 0.12.1. As a side note, although I get the correct answer, if I try accessing `np.ndarray.__code__`, I get the same error message. What version of numba are you using?

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: @JoshAdel numba.__version__ gives me 0.8.1

Comment: @user2357112 For various non-technical reasons, I can't show you the full stacktrace, but I will attach as much info as I can

Comment: It looks like it is trying to apply `@jit` to `a`, which is an array, not a function.

Comment: @AnthonyKong That version is in the stone ages given Numba's rapid development and beta-esque status. I would upgrade at least to 0.11. The latest version (0.12) is a major refactoring and there are a bunch of regressions so you might not want to get the latest, although Continuum is rapidly fixing it and in the long run, it will be better.

Comment: @JoshAdel Thanks! Please make it an answer so I can upvote/accept